# Python While Loop Test Scores

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python program that calculates the average of test scores and terminates when you enter -1. However, I'm having trouble getting it to also ignore test scores that are over 100. I want the program to take say the scores 90, 80, 105, 84, -1 and calculate the average of the 1st, 2nd, and 4th scores skipping the 3rd because it's over 100 and terminating with the-1

Here is what I have:

```
def main():
    sum = 0.0
    count = 0
    x = input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate) >> ")
    while x >= 0:
        sum = sum + x
        count = count + 1
        if x>100:
            break
        x = input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate) >> ")
    print "\nThe average of the numbers is", sum / count
    return
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement `if x > 100: break` causes the while loop execution to terminate, which isn't what you're looking for. You want it to keep going and ignore the number.

So you could do something like this:

```
while x >= 0:
    if x <= 100:
        # Do the calculations
```

Or, using Python's `continue` keyword, which automatically starts the next iteration of the parent loop. Like Martjin pointed out, you'd have to add another request in the body of the `if` statement:

```
while x >= 0:
    if x > 100:
        x = input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate) >> ")
        continue
    # Do the calculations
```

Comment: The latter form creates an endless loop as you are no longer asking the user to enter a new `x`. By using `continue` the `x = input(...)` statement is skipped, and `x` remains equal to a value over 100.

Comment: Now your the code has to ask for `x` in 3 different places though. The `if x <= 100` test is the better option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, it's just an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could add numbers to a list:

```
nums = []
...
    if x <= 100:
        nums.append(x)
```

Then the average is simply:

```
sum(nums) / float(len(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably collect all their entries as such:

```
entries = list()
while True:
    entry = input("Enter a test score (-1 to exit): ")
    if entry == -1: break
    entries.append(entry)
# we only get here after the user enters -1
entries = [entry for entry in entries if 0 <= entry <= 100]
entries_sum = sum(entries)
entries_average = entries_sum / len(entries)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already added to the sum and the count by the time you break:

```
sum = sum + x
count = count + 1
if x>100:
    break  # too late
```

Also, `break` ends the loop. You don't want that. So just avoid the sum and count, but keep looping and inputting:

```
while x >= 0:
    if x <= 100:
        sum = sum + x
        count = count + 1
    x = input("Enter a number (enter -1 to terminate) >> ")
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you test `if x>100`, you've already incremented the count and added to the sum. The second issue is then what you do on that condition - currently you're jumping out of the `while` loop, which you want to do `if x == -1` but not `if x>100`!

You could just change `break` to `sum -= x ; count -= 1`. But it would be more logical to have only added `x` to begin with:

```
while x >= 0:
    if x <= 100:
        count += 1
        sum += x
    x = input()
```